# How to fix a clipped outline of a <tr> in Safari?

Tags: css, safari

I'm trying to highlight the currently hovered table row with an outline. It works flawlessly in Firefox and Chrome... but Safari somehow clips the outline.

The 1st image shows Firefox... the 2nd is Safari.

[image: Firefox] [image: Safari]

The CSS is rather simple:

```
table tbody tr:hover {
    background-color: #48f2;
    outline: 3px solid #48f8;
}
```

**What could cause this behavior? Is this a known bug?**

PS: Hiding Safari (CMD+Tab) and showing it again without any mouse movement renders the `<tr>` properly... so I consider it a display bug. But maybe there is a workaround?

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49054516/11908502) may help you with it.

Comment: But `::before` and `::after` won't apply for `<tr>`... but I'll give it a try.

Comment: Yea my bad, it will treat it like a new `<tr>`. Maybe you can assign it to the new element and set its `position` as `absolute`.

Comment: Adding `table tbody tr:hover::before, table tbody tr:hover::after { content: ""; }` triggers the proper re-render... but adds another column and shifts all others. I've tried some things with `position` and other properties – didn't help so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried something obvious today... and it worked:

```
/* default state for Safari */
table tbody tr {
    outline: 3px solid #0000;
}
/* highlight table row upon hover */
table tbody tr:hover {
    background-color: #48f2;
    outline: 3px solid #48f8;
}
```

Simply setting a **transparent outline** for the **default state** solved this Safari bug. I guess Safari determines the outer boundings during initial render of the page and uses it to further optimize the rendering later.

Comment: it is works like a charm! For first outline better use 'transparent' color, on my opinion.